# I can't seem to get the game window to close on Close button press

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and am fairly interested in it.

I followed a tutorial on YouTube just to get a window setup and object that moves on keyboard press but the code I have for the program closing on the close window button doesn't work.

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))

pygame.display.set_caption("Simple Shooter")

x = 400
y = 400
width = 20
height = width
vel = 1

run = True

while run == True:
    pygame.time.delay(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            sys.exit()
            pygame.quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and y > vel:
        y -= vel
        
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and y < 800 - height - vel:
        y += vel
        
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 800 - width:
        x += vel
        
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I'm using pygame version 1.9.6 .

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare the `type` attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object to the type constant and not to the object itself:

<s>`if event == pygame.QUIT:`</s>

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

Comment: Damn, I overlooked that. Thanks !